# Read a CSV file in real time using Kafka Connect

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

how can I integrate Kafka connect with Kafka producer in java so that I can read a CSV file in real time? I am having a hard time finding any source related to this.

Right now I am using scala-ide to run a simple Kafka producer class, but have no idea on how to use it with Kafka connect.

Comment: There seem to be several examples on a quick Google search.  Try "kafka java example"

Comment: i know, i have tried this but all it shows the kafka java producer and consumer api without kafka connect. Also most of the kafka connect examples are written on linux machine but none are written in java.

Comment: Kafka Connect is a Java framework. It can be used on the any OS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Kafka Connect connector for reading CSV files already exists: https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir.

Yuo can see an example of it in action here: https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksql-in-action-enriching-csv-events-with-data-from-rdbms-into-AWS/

---

*Disclaimer: I wrote the above article, and work for Confluent on whose blog it was published*

Comment: thank you Robin, this project will definitely come in handy

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Connect has a producer already *built in*. You just need to use the right connector plugin. For reading a CSV file, the FileStreamSource connector which is part of Kafka should work. You can start the Kafka Connect probably in the standalone mode (see [Kafka docs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect)) and configure the connector. The example [config files](https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/config) which are part of Kafka should help you to get started.

Comment: Thank u Jakub, i will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Just another Kafka Connect plugin for reading CSV files  : https://github.com/streamthoughts/kafka-connect-file-pulse

Hope this project can help people looking for similar solution.

---

Disclaimer: I am one of the contributors to this project

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the casual spooldir connector is that you need to have the csv file inside the pod/ container of kafka-connect. It might not be secure for large sized files.